# elastic search match on multiple fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to retrieve documents that match the following criteria:

{ "field1: "string1" AND "field2": "string2"}

OR
{ "field1: "string3" AND "field2": "string4"}

OR

{ "field1: "string5" AND "field2": "string6"}

[I can do that for one set of conditions like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39507005/query-with-match-by-multiple-fields)

How to achieve that for multiple sets in a single query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply wrap all your OR conditions in a `bool/should` query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "field1": "string1"
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "field2": "string2"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "field1": "string3"
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "field2": "string4"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "field1": "string5"
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "field2": "string6"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I was afraid of looping in multiple clauses, but looks like there is no other way.

Comment: What do you mean by "looping"? What are you afraid of?

Comment: By looping I mean, how we are repeating the bool, and must query parts. If there are many pairs, then query could become quite big in size.

Comment: You should try it out and you will see that it won't really be a problem. But feel free to explain your use case in more details.

Comment: I tried and it worked. I am go with this for now and will accept this answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Instead of match and then must, would filter and terms work better? (I need to match those exact strings).

Comment: If you're doing exact searches and your fields are keyword fields, then the `match` query will actually translate internally to a `term` one and `must` will be equivalent to `filter`... So semantically it's the same, but nothing prevents you from running a filter/term instead of must/match.